# System encoding in TexStudio 2.8

Tags: texstudio, input-encodings

When recently updated my texstudio to v2.8, it turns out that the option of "system" encoding (i.e. system's native ASCII configuration) isn't one of the options when choosing an encoding.

Assuming I'm writing in some language whose ascii is not supported by texstudio, is there any way around this or should I just roll back to 2.7.X?

Comment: Hm... are you implying older versions support more encodings? Well if so, I didn't know but I find that unlikely. But if that is true, then yes, you should roll back to whatever version supported the encoding you need.

Comment: I *know*  that the "system" encoding option doesn't show in v2.8. I'm asking if they renamed it, or any other alternative is possible rather than rolling back.

Comment: Oh you mean it's a comfortable way of simply having it figure out the OS's system encoding. Ok I do not see that option either. I suppose you need to find out which encodings your OS support then. I believe that is just a google instance away. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am on TeXStudio 2.8 and I see "System" as a default encoding. It's available in the "Editor" menu.[image: Default_encoding]

Comment: 2.8.4 on Win 7 here and I do not have that option.

Comment: I don't :/. It might have something to do with the os or difference in the installed version.

Comment: Could be. I am working with the Ubuntu version. It's been a long time since I have worked with Windows, so I don't have any suggestions on how to fix this.